# Consulta de fechas en Django

Tags: django-models, sql

Quiero obtener datos sobre una misma fecha a partir de esta consulta:

Ejemplo:

```
fecha_inicio= 06/09/2017 fecha_final= 06/09/2017

    query=DetalleParte.objects.filter(fecha_creacion__range=(fecha_inicio,fecha_final)
```

Sin embargo la Query solo me trae datos cuando fecha_inicio es mayor o igual 
 y fecha_final menor, pero no respeta menor o igual

De igual forma intente realizar la misma query pero con lte y gte; sin embargo el
 resultado es el mismo

```
query=DetalleParte.objects.filter(fecha_creacion__gte=fecha_inicio, fecha_creacion__lte=fecha_final)
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto es porque el range toma la fechas a partir de las 12am en ambos casos, como se indica en la documentación:

> Filtrar un DateTimeField con fechas no incluirá elementos en el último
>   día, ya que los límites se interpretan como "0am en la fecha dada". Si
>   pub_date era un DateTimeField, la expresión anterior se convertiría en
>   este SQL: SELECT ... WHERE pub_date BETWEEN '2005-01-01 00:00:00' and
>   '2005-03-31 00:00:00';

Puedes verlo en: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#range

**Te recomiendo que modifiques la fecha poniendo como hora las 23:59, o mejor, suma un día a la fecha 'final'. Con eso podrás resolver el problema.**

Ej:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

fecha_inicio='06/09/2017'
fecha_final='06/09/2017'

d_fecha_inicio = datetime.strptime(fecha_inicio,'%d/%m/%Y')
d_fecha_final = datetime.strptime(fecha_final,'%d/%m/%Y') + timedelta(days=1)

query=DetalleParte.objects.filter(fecha_creacion__range=(d_fecha_inicio,d_fecha_final)
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola! Podrías decirme si solucionó tu problema? Gracias!

Comment: Marca
Exception Value: 
strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None

Comment: Lo tengo asi:                                                                                                                  fecha_inicio = request.GET.get('fechaA')
    fecha_final = request.GET.get('fechaB')
   
    d_fecha_inicio = datetime.strptime(fecha_inicio,'%d/%m/%Y')
    d_fecha_final = datetime.strptime(fecha_final,'%d/%m/%Y') + timedelta(days=1)                                                                                                      query=DetalleParte.objects.filter(fecha_creacion__range=(d_fecha_inicio,d_fecha_final)

Comment: El error 'Exception Value: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None' indica que la variable fecha_inicio y/o fecha_final poseen valor nulo. Haz un print('Valor fecha inicio:'+ str(fecha_inicio)) y también print('Valor fecha final:'+str(fecha_final)) antes de las conversiones para constatarlo. Si es asi (estoy prácticamente seguro que es el caso) debes verificar que vengan esos valores desde la pagina, posiblemente no se encuentren dentro del form.

Comment: Verificando. Es None cuando no se selecciona fechaFinal o fechaInico o viceversa; sin embargo si se seleccionan las dos fechas entonces si imprime las fechas dadas. Ejemplo:   Valor fecha inicio: 2017-09-01
Valor fecha final: 2017-09-14

Comment: Una forma de solucionarlo en este código, es evaluar si alguna de las fechas en None, y si es así, asignarle el valor por defecto que consideres  adecuado para cada uno de estas variables.

Comment: Si mi respuesta solucionó tu problema planteado en tu pregunta inicial, recuerda marcarlo! Esto nos motiva a seguir colaborando! Muchas gracias y disculpa la molestia!

Comment: Aun no lo he solucionado, se supone que las fechas vienen de  
    fecha_inicio = request.GET.get('fechaA')
    fecha_final = request.GET.get('fechaB')

Comment: Solo vendrán valores distintos de None si has asignado algun valor a las mismas cuando generaste la pagina, colocandole un valor en el campo del input. Sino se lo asigna al armar la pagina ni se le selecciona un valor luego, es correcto que llegue None al método.